# Cards Mucked Or Not?

Tags: texas-hold-em

In a tournament with 9 players at the table, 4 saw the flop, bet on the flop, 1 caller, bet on the turn, called, bet on the river, raised all in for the raiser, 45% of aggressors chips. He calls the all in but waits to see the all-in's cards, she (all-in) doesn't respond so about 30 seconds later he says call again. She throws her cards into the discard pile. He then turns his cards face up and proceeds to collect the pot. She then claims that she thought he folded and demands that her cards be retrieved. She had an ace high flush with A-9 diamonds, he had Q-6 diamonds. Ace high flush was the nuts. She announced her cards to prove that they were there. Does her hand stay mucked or does it get retrieved?

Comment: A good dealer helps avoid problems like this. When a player says "call", it's his obligation to tell the player to physically move his chips in, or toss in a single chip, or give him an all-in button, or something to make it visually clear that he has called. And he should announce it clearly and make sure the bettor understands. Still, it's the bettor's responsibility to follow the action and protect her hand, so she's out of luck.

Answer (score 2):

Hand stays mucked if it touched the muck, which you said it did. If it hasn't been killed by the dealer it can still be live, will depend on the TD, otherwise its dead.

Comment: Generally, this is correct. In the real world, it depends on the the people you're playing with (in a home/informal game) or the dealer/floorman (in a poker room). I've been at tables in similar situations where the floorman basically said "if everyone can agree on which cards were hers, we'll let her play them this time, even though they technically touched the muck."

Comment: That's true but home games are always different and can't be compared to casino games for ruling. Often its just friends and no one is really interesting in causing a big fight. Smaller/local cardclubs may do some things differently too, especially if you are a regular. Any major tournament, big casino or cardroom will make this ruling.